# How can I obtain the CDF of a function of two variables

Tags: probability-theory, cumulative-distribution-functions, random-functions

Consider two nonnegative random variables, $X$ and $Y$.
Assume that their PDF, i.e., $f_X(x)$ and $f_Y(y)$ are given.
Assume that an arbitrary function $g:X\times Y\to\mathbb{R_{\ge0}}$ is given.
However, we don't know the PDF of $Z=g(X,Y)$.

Then, for a given constant value $\gamma>0$, I want to derive $\Pr\left[g(X,Y) \le \gamma \right]$.

---

Let us define a function $h$ such that $$g(x,y)\le\gamma \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad x\le h(y,\gamma),$$
where $\Leftrightarrow$ denotes the *if and only if* symbol.
Then, is the following equation correct?
$$\Pr\left[f(X,Y)\le\gamma\right] = \int_0^\infty \left( \int_0^{h(y,\gamma)}f_{X}(x)\,\text{d}x\right)f_Y(y)\,\text{d}y.$$

Comment: Correct if such a function $h$ exists and  $X$ an $Y$ are independent. You cannot say anything about CDF of  $Z$ in general.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks a lot. I was suddenly confused about this and asked a question.